# Cannot drag and drop images to the images folder in android studio

Tags: flutter

As new to flutter i am unable to drag and drop images in android studio.
Android studio gives a message when i try to drag and drop the image in the images Folder.

"move refactoring is not available while indexing is in progress android studio"

Comment: Wait a little for the indexing to be completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply place(copy and paste) your images to where the project is available in the Computer Directory, like if C:\flutter_project\images\image1.jpg.
**Place your images in the Project Directory directly and it would appear in the Project Structure of IDE.**

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I didn't even need to place it in the location, i actually just used keyboard shortcuts for copy/paste. Not sure why the drag and drop functionality suddenly broke.

Comment: This way works for me in PyCharm too. Thanks.